MS Graph - List events (read) - Recurring events
I would like to ask you for an help related to the reading my callendar events from MS Exchange by MS Graph API.
Issue: My code do not "download" the recurring Events from calendar, all others are downloaded.
Note:

Im successfully authenticated OAuth2 --> so this code is not listed here
Code it self is called from another cade so variables are hand over. I use this for testing:


Filter_Start_Date = "2024-12-11"
Filter_End_Date = "2024-12-11"

My code:
# Update filters)
Filter_Start_Date = Filter_Start_Date + "T00:00:00Z"
Filter_End_Date = Filter_End_Date + "T00:00:00Z"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Prefer": 'outlook.timezone="Europe/Paris"'}

params = {
    "$filter": f"start/dateTime ge \'{Filter_Start_Date}\' and end/dateTime le \'{Filter_End_Date}\'",  #! To be done --> maybe here is some issue with filtering data !!!!
    "$orderby": f"start/dateTime desc",
    "$top": 1000,
    "$count": "true",
    "$select": "subject, start, end, categories, recurrence, showAs, location, isAllDay, bodyPreview"}

Events_downloaded = {}
events_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{username}/events"
events_response = requests.get(url=events_url, headers=headers, params=params)

Counter = 0 
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Init page 
    Events = events_response.json()

Can anyone tell me what do I do wrong?
Thank you
Jan Vaško

To include recurring events, use the /calendarView endpoint instead of /events, and ensure the date range in your $filter captures the full day (e.g., T23:59:59Z). Also, handle pagination if the result contains more than 1000 events.

Try to set different values for Filter_Start_Date and Filter_Start_Date, but calendar view seems to be better endpoint, because it returns occurrences.

For sample, I created a recurring event using Microsoft Graph API:

To read the recurring events make use of below code:
access_token = "AccessToken"
username = "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"  

# Define start and end date for filtering events (adjust these dates based on your needs)
Filter_Start_Date = "2024-12-12T00:00:00Z"
Filter_End_Date = "2024-12-31T23:59:59Z"  

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Prefer": 'outlook.timezone="Europe/Paris"'  
}

params = {
    "startDateTime": Filter_Start_Date,
    "endDateTime": Filter_End_Date,
    "$orderby": "start/dateTime",
    "$top": 1000,  
    "$select": "id,subject,start,end,location,recurrence,seriesMasterId"
}

# Endpoint to fetch all events (including recurrence details)
events_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{username}/events"

response = requests.get(events_url, headers=headers, params=params)

if response.status_code == 200:
    events = response.json()
    print("Fetched Events:")
    for event in events["value"]:
        print(f"Subject: {event['subject']}")
        print(f"Start: {event['start']['dateTime']}")
        print(f"End: {event['end']['dateTime']}")
        print(f"Location: {event['location']['displayName']}")
        # Recurrence might not be present for occurrences, so check for it on the seriesMasterId
        if "recurrence" in event:
            print(f"Recurrence: {event['recurrence']}")
        elif "seriesMasterId" in event:
            print(f"Event is part of a recurring series (Series ID): {event['seriesMasterId']}")
        else:
            print("Recurrence: None")
        print("--------------------------------------------------")
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.json())


If still the issue persists, check the below:

Make use of /calendarView endpoint instead of /events. Refer this SO Thread by  Slipstream.
Make sure to pass different values for Filter_Start_Date and Filter_Start_Date.
Try to handle pagination if the result contains more than 1000 events.


Rukmini - thank you actually changing of Endpoint correct the issue.  I just didn't share code for paging which is actually implemented.

Okay so you use calendar view endpoint
